# Shopify: Display results of Liquid Metafields call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm trying to add a call to a metafield I created for a product inside of a .js file so I can display some custom data. Instead of seeing that data, I'm just setting the overall code. This is the code I'm currently adding:

```
{%- if product.metafields.my_fields.subscription_descriptions != blank -%}
  <p>{{ product.metafields.my_fields.subscription_descriptions }}</p>
{%- endif -%}
```

It's all part of what looks like standard HTML, so I'm just looking for the solution on how to add it so my metafield displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem? You are not seeing the data you expect? Are you sure that metafield resource exists in that namespace, for that key? If it does, have you tried extracting it using the value method?

```
{{ product.metafields.my_fields.subscription_descriptions.value }}
```

Sometimes that is necessary.

Comment: I'm only seeing the actual code. So if I paste what's up above and visit the product, that's what I see.

Comment: You ave to explain what you are doing. You cannot call Javascript with Liquid. So that is confusing. But if you are rendering the Liquid snippet above in a Liquid file, you will have data that you can then use in Javascript. That is how it works. Liquid first... Javascript second.

Comment: I am explaining what I am trying to do. Display the contents of a metafield inside of JavaScript.

Comment: It is dead simple. 

<script>  let fooBar = "{{ product.namespace.key.value }}"  </script>

Has always worked perfect for me, a million times. Boom Metafield in Javascript.